# Integrating a gradient and matching terms automatically

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector, vector-calculus

I am trying to integrate a function $\nabla w(x,y)$ indefinitely knowing both components of $\nabla w(x,y)$. I have a function `dw[x_,y_]` that I have defined. I then use `Integrate[dw[x, y][[1]], x]` and `Integrate[dw[x, y][[2]], y]` to get my two expressions for $w(x,y)$. But now I want to match terms in each expression automatically and impose a condition to solve for the one integration constant which is independent of $x$ and $y$. The function `Collect` does not seem to do it. Any tips?

Comment: Show us the function you are working with. Hard to say otherwise.

Comment: Take $\nabla w = \{x + y,x+y,0\}$ for example. We know from calculus that we get two expressions for $w$: $w = 0.5 x^2 + yx + f(y)$ and $w = xy + 0.5 y^2 + g(x)$. I want mathematica to give me the final answer, which is $w = 0.5x^2 + xy + 0.5y^2 + C$, where $C$ is a constant independent of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 4):

Won't necessarily work in general, but just have *Mathematica* do the integration for you:

```
dw[x_, y_] = {x + y, x + y, 0};
First@DSolve[{D[f[x, y], x] == dw[x, y][[1]], D[f[x, y], y] == dw[x, y][[2]]}, f[x, y], {x, y}]
(* {f[x, y] -> x^2/2 + x y + y^2/2 + C[1]} *)
```

---

Here's a way to do it by hand. This method tests at the end for the exactness of the differential, which is nice, so I will illustrate it with an exact differential and an inexact one:

```
dw[x_, y_] = {x + y, x}
ws = {Integrate[dw[x, y][[1]], x] + f[y],  Integrate[dw[x, y][[2]], y] + g[x]}
sols = Join @@ {
  Solve[0 == Select[Subtract @@ ws // Expand, FreeQ[#, x] &], f[y]], 
  Solve[0 == Select[Subtract @@ ws // Expand, FreeQ[#, y] &], g[x]]
 }
MapThread[ReplaceAll, {ws, sols}]
SameQ @@ %
```

[image]

and

```
dw[x_, y_] = {x + y, x^2}
ws = {Integrate[dw[x, y][[1]], x] + f[y], Integrate[dw[x, y][[2]], y] + g[x]}
sols = Join @@ {
  Solve[0 == Select[Subtract @@ ws // Expand, FreeQ[#, x] &], f[y]], 
  Solve[0 == Select[Subtract @@ ws // Expand, FreeQ[#, y] &], g[x]]
 }
MapThread[ReplaceAll, {ws, sols}]
SameQ @@
```

[image]